The relatioship between the input complex vector and output vector after multiplication with a matrix
Assuming I have the vector $x \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$, the real and imaginary parts of the vector $x$ are concatenated as $s = [\mathcal{R}(x); \mathcal{I}(x)]$, where $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{I}$ represent the real and imaginary parts of the vector $x$, respectively.
The vector $s$ is multiplied with a real unitary matrix $W \in \mathbb{R}^{2N \times 2N}$ as $r = W \times s$. Then, the complex matrix $y \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ is written using the vector $r$ as $y = r_{(1:N)} + j \times r_{(N+1:2N)}$.
My question, how can I write the relationship between the original vector $x$ and output $y$ using the complex matrix $Z$ such that $y = Z \times x$?

Unless $W$ has a the specific structure
$$
W = \pmatrix{A & -B\ B & A}
$$
for $N \times N$ matrices $A,B \in \Bbb R^{N \times N}$, no such matrix $Z$ can exist.
